# 1D Divergence Theorem for a Tensor

Tags: calculus, tensors, divergence-theorem

Consider the 2-rank tensor $Q_{ij}$:

$$Q_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix} 
Q_{11} & Q_{12} & Q_{13} \\
Q_{21} & Q_{22} & Q_{33} \\
Q_{31} & Q_{32} & Q_{33}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Consider then the integral:
$$\int_L{\nabla\cdot (\nabla \cdot Q)*dr}.$$

How would I apply the divergence theorem to this integral? From other answers on stack exchange, I expect:

$$\int_L{\nabla\cdot (\nabla \cdot Q)*dr} = (\nabla \cdot Q)|_a^b$$

However, for the particular problem I am working on, I expect a scalar answer from evaluating this integral (it would be non-sensical for this quantity to be a vector).

In 2 and 3 dimensions, applying the divergence equates the volume integral of the divergence of a quantity to the flux normal to the boundary--keyword being normal. Thus, this problem doesn't seem to arise.

Am I just missing this normal unit vector when applying the 1D divergence theorem, i.e., misapplying the theorem?

Thank you!

Comment: What is $L$ here? Also, for the record, is $*$ here just scalar multiplication?

Comment: Yes * is scalar multiplication. L is just a line in space (e.g. from point a to b in cartesian coordinates).